# Why does my PC beep when I printout more than 7 console outputs in C++ console application?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, console-application, iostream

```
// Convert Int to Char

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    for (short i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {
       char newChar = i;
       cout << i << " = " << newChar << "\n";
    }

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Last output, number 7 does not show any character, only empty space.

Comment: I don't think this is a question to be downvoted. Even if the question could be considered trivial, the situation descrived above (*The computer plays sounds when I'm sending characters to the screen!!!*) could be non-trivial for newbbies and people with no knoweledge about ASCII and how it works.

Comment: You may want to cast the `char` variable to `int` before printing or use `int` variable to begin with.

Comment: You mean cout << char( i ) << " = " << newChar << "\n"; ?

Comment: ASCII? It's unlikely that someone using C++/CLI has a console that uses ASCII. This _is a nitpick_ but one might as well know which character set and encoding ("**code page**") one's console is using. Do, `chcp` to find out then check Wikipedia for more info.

Comment: My cmd threw Active code page : 852

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852

Comment: I think it is important to know what character set and encoding you are using and also to realize that other users, other files, etc might be using a different one. My comment was a nitpick because by design almost all character sets are supersets of ASCII and almost all have encodings that produce the same byte sequence for those characters as ASCII. So, as others have said, 7 is the bell character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ascii code 7 is the [bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) character, which should make your PC beep.

Answer (score 3):

[ascii character](http://www.asciitable.com/) `7` is the [bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) or `\a`, which is why you hear a beep, quoting the article:

> In ASCII and Unicode the character with the value 7 is BEL. [...] In the C programming language (created in 1972), the bell character can be placed in a string or character constant with \a. ('a' stands for "alert" or "audible" and was chosen because \b was already used for the backspace character.)

The C++ draft standard section `2.2` *Character sets* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The **basic execution character set and the basic execution wide-character set shall each contain** all the members of the basic source character set, plus control **characters representing alert**, backspace, and carriage return, plus a null character [...]

and then `Table 5`  *escape sequences* contains this line:

```
alert BEL \a
```

Answer (score 3):

ASCII 7 is `\a`, or `BEL`. implementation may choose to play the beep. C++ interstates this from C:

> #### C99 §5.2.2 Character display semantics
>
> `\a` (alert) Produces an audible or visible alert without changing the active position.

Answer (score 2):

7 is the ASCII code for "bell", meaning that the console should make a noise if possible. Once upon a time, it would literally make a teleprinter ring a bell.